# Способы образования слов

Tags: словообразование

Какими способами образованы слова: *нередко, умысел, улучшают*?

Answer (score 2):

*Нередко* — префиксация, *умысел* и *улучшать* — суффиксация.

Answer (score 1):

Извините, категорически не согласна. 
Улучшать — делать лучше. Одновременное присоединение приставки и суффикса. (у+лучш+а)
Умысел — Какой вы тут видите суффикс? Это бессуффиксный способ (нулевая аффиксация) от глагола умыслить. 
Со словом "нередко" сложнее. Наречия на -о(е) образуются от качественных прилагательных суффиксальным способом (нередкий - нередко). Но в некоторых пособиях ранее действительно был указан приставочный способ.

Comment: 1. Охотно извиняю.
2. В глагольных видовых парах форма НСВ образуется от формы СВ: *улучшать << улучшить.* Префиксально-суффиксальным способом образована как раз форма СВ: *улучшить << лучше.*
3. Абстрактные существительные со значением действия образуются от соответствующих глаголов **суффиксацией,** при этом графическая и/или фонетическая непредставленность суффикса не должна нас смущать: (принято считать, что) он есть.

Comment: 4. Здесь имеем дело с неединственной мотивацией: слово мотивируется одновременно двумя словами, отличающимися от него одинаковым количеством формантов. При этом мотивация наречием *(редко)* является основной, а прилагательным *(нередкий)* — сопровождающей.
Т.о., во всех трёх случаях вы ошибаетесь.
С ув.